# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() with valid JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm confused why I'm getting the error Invalid argument supplied for foreach().  I've seen a few other threads on here with the same error but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I pull my JSON out of the database (into $runStatus['fldRawFiles']) and have:

```
$selectedFiles= json_decode($runStatus['fldRawFiles'], true);
```

Which echoed out gives me:

```
{"6":{"files":[],"packages":["program_data/6/packages/1646756076.zip"],"scripts":["program_data/6/scripts/MEER_munger.py"]}}
```

Then I try to use:

```
foreach($selectedFiles as $key=>$d){    
       $programname=$this->extractor_model->get_program_name($key);
//more code here
}
```

But I get the error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I ran the JSON through a validator and it says it's valid.  I've tried leaving out the true argument, but get the same result.  I've also tried putting (array) in front of json_decode, but then my key is 0 and not the key that I want from the JSON (6).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide the result of `var_dump($selectedFiles);` *right before* the foreach?

Comment: The value you said echoed out `{"6":{"files":[] ...` <- this actually is string and it is JSON string. So, you can't do `foreach() {...}`. You have to `json_decode()` this string again and you will get object type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you echo `$selectedFiles`
after doing `$selectedFiles = json_decode($runStatus['fldRawFiles'], true);`

And you get

```
{"6":{"files":[],"packages":["program_data/6/packages/1646756076.zip"],"scripts":["program_data/6/scripts/MEER_munger.py"]}}
```

Then that field contains more JSON, so decode it again

```
foreach( json_decode($selectedFiles) as $key=>$d){
    echo $key;
}
```